# How do I handle an error within an NGRX effect where there is no inner-observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

Consider a normal function that can throw an exception ie:

```
function canThrow(){
  ...
  throw 'error';
}
```

I want to use that in an NGRX effect:

```
public myEffect$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(DoSomethingAction),
      map(() =>
        canThrow(),
      ),
      map(() => SucceededAction()),
      catchError(() => of(FailedAction())),
    ),
  );
```

However this results in `FailedAction` being emitted then completing, which kills the effect - similarly to when `catchError` is not piped from a function returning an observable.

Here `canThrow` does *not* return an observable.

How can I structure the code so that error is handled but the effect is not terminated via the completion?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a flattening operator like `switchMap` assuming `canThrow` does not return an observable. https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-mk5bla?file=index.ts

You can learn more here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap

```
import { of, map } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

of({
  type: 'some action',
})
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() => {
      try {
        const result = throwError();
        return of(result).pipe(map(() => ({ type: 'success action' })));
      } catch (error) {
        return of({ type: 'failed action' });
      }
    })
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);



function throwError() {
  if (Math.random() > 0) {
    throw new Error('kaboom');
  } else {
    return 'some data';
  }
}
```

Comment: Also if you don't know what a flattening operator is, I highly recommend reading and watching the following: https://medium.com/@shairez/a-super-ninja-trick-to-learn-rxjss-switchmap-mergemap-concatmap-and-exhaustmap-forever-88e178a75f1b

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with switchMap etc. I had thought of an approach similar to this but it seems long winded effectively wrapping a plain function so it plays nicely with `catchError`. I was/am hoping for a cleaner approach, if one exists.

Comment: It's challenging with a function that does not return an observable. catchError will work if the observable is an error. You could write a function which invokes some function, catches the error, and returns it as an observable error. That would allow you to use catchError

Answer (score 0):

I came up with 2 ways of achieving this:

**map to try/catch without observables**

Along the lines of Alex's answer, a somewhat imperative approach using a `try..catch` but the `switchMap` and conversion of returned actions to observables is not required:

```
public myEffect$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(DoSomethingAction),
      map(() => {
        try {
          canThrow();
          return SucceededAction();
        }
        catch {
          return FailedAction();
        }
      }),
    ),
  );
```

**switchMap with defer/of and catchError**

A more rxjs oriented solution, which creates an observable wrapping `canThrow` and pipes the response which allows use of `catchError`:

```
public myEffect$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(DoSomethingAction),
      switchMap(() =>
        defer(() => of(canThrow())),
      ).pipe(
        map(() => SucceededAction()),
        catchError(() => of(FailedAction())),
      ),
    ),
  );
```